# Objective-C &JSONKit POST issue

Tags: objective-c, post, jsonkit

I'm trying to post to a rails backend from Objective-C and JSONKit and am having difficulty getting my results published.  I keep getting back a null recordset from my server.

```
[dictionary setValue:(@"bar")  forKey:@"foo"];

NSString *JSON = [dictionary JSONString];
NSData *theData = [JSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: myUrl];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [theData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
NSError *error = NULL;
NSURLResponse *response = nil;

[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json-rpc" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:theData];
NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                       returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(resultString);
```

Is there something I'm missing?  the JSON seems to be serializing correctly

{"foo":"bar"}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Apart from the parentheses in setValue:(@"bar"), which should not be the problem, I do not see anything strange here. Try to change the cachePolicy of the request to NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData, it might help.

Comment: Thanks, Davyd.i tried adding [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData]; to the above and I'm still having the issue.

Comment: Does the server get the data you send?

Comment: i ended up changing just this line 
setValue:@"application/json-rpc" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

to 

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

and it worked.  Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 1):

Just changed the setValue from json-rpc to json and it worked like a champ.

```
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
**[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];**
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData];
[request setHTTPBody:theData];
```

Comment: Good catch. I was not sure about content type, I thought you put those one for a reason. It is good you've found it.